# WSO2 API Manager ELK Analytics - API without security generate metrics Error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, elk

I wanted to see if my api could be tracked when I'm turning off security in the resource section. But I found this error and the api log cannot be tracked in elk. It won't generate any log in apim_metrics.log

I'm using wso2 apim 4.2

Is there anyone know how to fix this? or is there any way to make an anonymous hit could be tracked?

[2023-10-23 12:16:13,756] ERROR - AbstractRequestDataPublisher Error occurred when publishing event.
org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.exception.MetricReportingException: userName is missing in metric data. This metric event will not be processed further.
at org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.reporter.elk.ELKMetricEventBuilder.validate(ELKMetricEventBuilder.java:79) ~[org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client_1.2.3.jar:?]
at org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.reporter.AbstractMetricEventBuilder.build(AbstractMetricEventBuilder.java:32) ~[org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client_1.2.3.jar:?]
at org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.reporter.elk.ELKCounterMetric.incrementCount(ELKCounterMetric.java:49) ~[org.wso2.am.analytics.publisher.client_1.2.3.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.analytics.publishers.impl.AbstractRequestDataPublisher.publish(AbstractRequestDataPublisher.java:73) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.analytics_9.28.116.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.analytics.collectors.impl.SuccessRequestDataCollector.collectData(SuccessRequestDataCollector.java:95) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.analytics_9.28.116.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.analytics.collectors.impl.GenericRequestDataCollector.collectData(GenericRequestDataCollector.java:46) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.common.analytics_9.28.116.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.analytics.AnalyticsMetricsHandler.handleResponseOutFlow_aroundBody8(AnalyticsMetricsHandler.java:95) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.28.116.jar:?]
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.analytics.AnalyticsMetricsHandler.handleResponseOutFlow(AnalyticsMetricsHandler.java:1) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_9.28.116.jar:?]
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:188) ~[synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20.jar:4.0.0-wso2v20]
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:574) ~[synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20.jar:4.0.0-wso2v20]
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.SendMediator.mediate(SendMediator.java:123) ~[synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20.jar:4.0.0-wso2v20]
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:110) ~[synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20.jar:4.0.0-wso2v20]
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:72) ~[synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20.jar:4.0.0-wso2v20]
at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158) ~[synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20.jar:4.0.0-wso2v20]
at org.apache.synapse.api.Resource.process(Resource.java:342) ~[synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20.jar:4.0.0-wso2v20]
at org.apache.synapse.api.API.process(API.java:416) ~[synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20.jar:4.0.0-wso2v20]
at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(AbstractApiHandler.java:108) ~[synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20.jar:4.0.0-wso2v20]
at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.identifyAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:128) ~[synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20.jar:4.0.0-wso2v20]
at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.dispatchToAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:55) ~[synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20.jar:4.0.0-wso2v20]
at org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RestRequestHandler.java:90) ~[synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20.jar:4.0.0-wso2v20]
at org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.process(RestRequestHandler.java:63) ~[synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20.jar:4.0.0-wso2v20]
at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:54) ~[synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20.jar:4.0.0-wso2v20]
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:346) ~[synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20.jar:4.0.0-wso2v20]
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:644) ~[synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20.jar:4.0.0-wso2v20]
at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:219) ~[synapse-core_4.0.0.wso2v20.jar:4.0.0-wso2v20]
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v83.jar:?]
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:304) ~[synapse-nhttp-transport_4.0.0.wso2v20.jar:?]
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v83.jar:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]

Answer (score 0):

This was identified and fixed recently through [1]. If you are using the open source version of the product, you will have to add this change and build the product again to get the issue resolved.

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/pull/12170

Comment: I've tried to rebuild the product (with the newest update) and the issue is still not resolved. I'm still getting the same error, do you have any insight on this?

Comment: Are you using the newly built product? If the fix is there, you should not be seeing this issue.

Comment: yes, i'm using 9.28.187-SNAPSHOT for carbon-apimgt and apim 4.2.0-snapshot. I'm still seeing this error even after cleaning all of m2 folder before re-building the package